# How to create and send a UInt8Array over WebSockets with Swift

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, uint8array

I have a NodeJS Socket IO server that uses a `UInt8Array` to send and receive packets of data, I am trying to write a client in iOS and Swift and as a complete newbie I am unsure how to create a `UInt8Array` in Swift and send using [Socket.IO](https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift), I have tried several different ways to achieve this but have so far been unable to crack this

```
let f = [115, 7, 0]
self.socket?.emit("message", f)
```

The above code does not work as the values are not `UInt8`, if I do the following

```
let f = [UInt8(115), UInt8(7), UInt8(0)]
self.socket?.emit("message", f);
```

and as suggested by @zisoft

```
let f: [UInt8] = [115, 7, 0]
self.socket?.emit("message", f) // get error here that Argument type '[UInt8]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'
```

If i try casting `f as AnyObject` i then get a runtime error instead

Any help would be greatly appreciated as pulling my hair out with this one (and believe me I haven't got much hair left to pull out)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your array as of type `UInt8` like so:

```
let f : [UInt8] = [115,7,0]
```

Comment: I have tried that but then i get `Argument type '[UInt8]' does not confirm to expected type 'AnyObject'` when passing to `self.socket?.emit("message", f).  I have tried casting to `AnyObject` using `f as AnyObject` but this errors at runtime